# search for file and execute macro using a textbox control

Tags: vba, excel, textbox

I am trying to use a textbox and search button in an excel sheet, masterfile. I want to be able to type a file name into a textbox and hit the search button and have it search in a particular folder for that file, open the file, then run my macro on that file (which gathers data from the sheet and puts it into my masterfile and closes the file).

I have code written but this line, `If Dir(TDS_PATH & TextBox1.Text) <> "" Then`, will get skipped over and passed to `Else` even when the textbox is not empty... so clearly it must think it is empty? Thank you for any help in advance!

Can anyone help me figure out where I am going wrong?
The image is what my masterfile looks like and my code is for the search button and my macro

**UPDATE**
I have gotten the button to correctly open the file but I am trying to alter my macro to get it to read properly/ make it compatible with the next textbox opening file method but it is not working properly, more info in the comments below. Any ideas?

[image]

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


'Set folder path where the file is located
Const TDS_PATH = "C:\Users\trembos\Documents\TDS\progress\"

'Clear out any info on current page
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:D7557").Clear

'TextBox1.Text = "Enter File Name Here"
'TextBox1.Font.Italic = True

'input checking
If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Please enter a file to search for")
End If

'If the File we are searching for exists in the path
If TextBox1.Text <> "" Then

    'Disable screen updating for performance/aesthetics
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Open the workbook we searched for (ReadOnly)
    Workbooks.Open TDS_PATH & TextBox1.Text, ReadOnly:=True

    'Copy the range we are interested in
    ActiveWorkbook.Application.Run "Search"

    'Close the file
    ActiveWorkbook.Close (False)

    'Re-enable screen updating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Else
    'Let the user know if the file is not found
    MsgBox ("File not found!")
End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_GotFocus()
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    TextBox1.Font.Italic = False
End Sub
```

My macro code is here:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Search()

    Const ROW_HEADER As Long = 10

    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim StartSht As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim hc As Range, hc1 As Range, hc2 As Range, hc3 As Range, d As Range

    Set StartSht = Workbooks("masterfile.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set hc1 = HeaderCell(StartSht.Range("B1"), "HOLDER")
    Set hc2 = HeaderCell(StartSht.Range("C1"), "CUTTING TOOL")

    'create an instance of the FileSystemObject
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'get the folder object
    i = 2


'(2)

            'Open folder and file name, do not update links
            'Set WB = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=MyFolder & objFile.Name, UpdateLinks:=0)
            'Set ws = WB.ActiveSheet
'(3)
                'find CUTTING TOOL on the source sheet
                Set hc = HeaderCell(ws.Cells(ROW_HEADER, 1), "CUTTING TOOL")
                If Not hc Is Nothing Then

                    Set dict = GetValues(hc.Offset(1, 0))
                    If dict.count > 0 Then
                        Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                        'add the values to the masterfile, column 3
                        d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
                    End If
                Else
                    'header not found on source worksheet
                End If
'(4)
                'find HOLDER on the source sheet
                Set hc3 = HeaderCell(ws.Cells(ROW_HEADER, 1), "HOLDER")
                If Not hc3 Is Nothing Then

                    Set dict = GetValues(hc3.Offset(1, 0))
                    If dict.count > 0 Then
                        Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc1.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                        'add the values to the master list, column 2
                        d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
                    End If
                Else
                    'header not found on source worksheet
                End If
'(5)
            With WB
               'print TDS information
                For Each ws In .Worksheets
                        'print the file name to Column 1
                        StartSht.Cells(i, 1) = objFile.Name
                        'print TDS name from J1 cell to Column 4
                        With ws
                            .Range("J1").Copy StartSht.Cells(i, 4)
                        End With
                        i = GetLastRowInSheet(StartSht) + 1
                'move to next file
                Next ws
'(6)
                'close, do not save any changes to the opened files
                .Close SaveChanges:=False
            End With
    'turn screen updating back on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
'(7)
End Sub

'(8)
'get all unique column values starting at cell c
Function GetValues(ch As Range) As Object
    Dim dict As Object, rng As Range, c As Range, v
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each c In ch.Parent.Range(ch, ch.Parent.Cells(Rows.count, ch.Column).End(xlUp)).Cells
        v = Trim(c.Value)
        If Len(v) > 0 And Not dict.exists(v) Then
            dict.Add c.Address, v
        End If
    Next c
    Set GetValues = dict
End Function

'(9)
'find a header on a row: returns Nothing if not found
Function HeaderCell(rng As Range, sHeader As String) As Range
    Dim rv As Range, c As Range
    For Each c In rng.Parent.Range(rng, rng.Parent.Cells(rng.Row, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft)).Cells
        If Trim(c.Value) = sHeader Then
            Set rv = c
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c
    Set HeaderCell = rv
End Function

'(10)
Function GetLastRowInColumn(theWorksheet As Worksheet, col As String)
    With theWorksheet
        GetLastRowInColumn = .Range(col & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function

'(11)
Function GetLastRowInSheet(theWorksheet As Worksheet)
Dim ret
    With theWorksheet
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            ret = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            ret = 1
        End If
    End With
    GetLastRowInSheet = ret
End Function
```

Comment: You're getting "file not found" every time?

Comment: I have been troubleshooting it and it just was not opening the correct location. Now it seems to be working but I cannot get the macro I'm assigning to it to work properly. I haved edited my code above. In section (3) I get an error on `Set hc = HeaderCell(ws.Cells(ROW_HEADER, 1), "CUTTING TOOL")`  saying: _Object variable or With block variable not set_ @Raystafarian

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30716302/vba-troubleshooting-code-for-macro-and-textbox @Raystafarian

Comment: If you're going to create a new question, at least make this question clear as to what it was asking and how it was solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


'Set folder path where the file is located
Const TDS_PATH = "C:\Users\trembos\Documents\TDS\progress\"

'Clear out any info on current page
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:D7557").Clear


'TextBox1.Text = ".xlsx"
'TextBox1.Font.Italic = True

'input checking
If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Please enter a file to search for")
End If

'If the File we are searching for exists in the path
If TextBox1.Text <> "" Then

    'Disable screen updating for performance/aesthetics
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Open the workbook we searched for (ReadOnly)
    Workbooks.Open TDS_PATH & TextBox1.Text, ReadOnly:=True

    'Copy the range we are interested in
    ActiveWorkbook.Application.Run "Search"

    'Close the file
    ActiveWorkbook.Close (False)

    'Re-enable screen updating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Else
    'Let the user know if the file is not found
    MsgBox ("File not found!")
End If
End Sub

'if you click on the textbox, it will empty any contents
Private Sub TextBox1_GotFocus()
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    TextBox1.Font.Italic = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Either the textbox is empty or the file cannot be found.

Do you add at the end of your file name .xls?

You can add in your code a wildcard in the end so that you don't have to input the file extension every time.

```
If Dir(TDS_PATH & TextBox1.Text & "*") <> "" Then
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I did finally get it to work by just taking out the TDS_PATH portion since it wasn't necessary. It will now step through the program and starts to run my macro; unfortunately, I am having problems getting my macro code to work with this particular task. I have attached the code in my original question. Any ideas? @TylerDurden

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30716302/vba-troubleshooting-code-for-macro-and-textbox @TylerDurden