# Troubleshooting code for macro and textbox

Tags: vba, excel, textbox

I have a working macro that loops through folder to open files and get important info from the columns of names "HOLDER" and "CUTTING TOOL" and printing all the info to one excel document, masterfile.

I have created a textbox w/ search button that I can enter one file name into and it will go to that folder and open the file.

I am trying to alter my macro and put it into the code for the search button to the get the important info from the columns of "HOLDER" and `"CUTTING TOOL"` and print it into the excel document, masterfile. Here is the working macro and my altered macro tailored for the search button.

Currently I am stuck in section (3) of the altered macro on the line `Set hc = HeaderCell(ws.Cells(ROW_HEADER, 1), "CUTTING TOOL")` giving the error *Object variable or With block variable not set*
Any ideas?

**UPDATE**
I somehow passed through the `Set hc = HeaderCell(ws.Cells(ROW_HEADER, 1), "CUTTING TOOL")` error in section (3) and another one that popped up, same error, in the similar line in sectin (4). Now I am getting the same error, *Object variable or With block variable not set* , in section (5) on the line

```
StartSht.Cells(i, 1) = objFile.Name
```

I'm not sure if this has to do with that line of code, the fact that it is utilizing `ws` and `.Worksheets` , or something entirely different. Any advice would be wonderful!

**ALTERED MACRO:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Search()

    Const ROW_HEADER As Long = 10

    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim StartSht As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim hc As Range, hc1 As Range, hc2 As Range, hc3 As Range, d As Range

    Set StartSht = Workbooks("masterfile.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set hc1 = HeaderCell(StartSht.Range("B1"), "HOLDER")
    Set hc2 = HeaderCell(StartSht.Range("C1"), "CUTTING TOOL")

    'create an instance of the FileSystemObject
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'get the folder object
    i = 2


'(2)

            'Open folder and file name, do not update links
            'Set WB = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=MyFolder & objFile.Name, UpdateLinks:=0)
            'Set ws = WB.ActiveSheet
'(3)
                'find CUTTING TOOL on the source sheet
                Set hc = HeaderCell(ws.Cells(ROW_HEADER, 1), "CUTTING TOOL")
                If Not hc Is Nothing Then

                    Set dict = GetValues(hc.Offset(1, 0))
                    If dict.count > 0 Then
                        Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                        'add the values to the masterfile, column 3
                        d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
                    End If
                Else
                    'header not found on source worksheet
                End If
'(4)
                'find HOLDER on the source sheet
                Set hc3 = HeaderCell(ws.Cells(ROW_HEADER, 1), "HOLDER")
                If Not hc3 Is Nothing Then

                    Set dict = GetValues(hc3.Offset(1, 0))
                    If dict.count > 0 Then
                        Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc1.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                        'add the values to the master list, column 2
                        d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
                    End If
                Else
                    'header not found on source worksheet
                End If
'(5)
            With WB
               'print TDS information
                For Each ws In .Worksheets
                        'print the file name to Column 1
                        StartSht.Cells(i, 1) = objFile.Name
                        'print TDS name from J1 cell to Column 4
                        With ws
                            .Range("J1").Copy StartSht.Cells(i, 4)
                        End With
                        i = GetLastRowInSheet(StartSht) + 1
                'move to next file
                Next ws
'(6)
                'close, do not save any changes to the opened files
                .Close SaveChanges:=False
            End With
    'turn screen updating back on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
'(7)
End Sub

'(8)
'get all unique column values starting at cell c
Function GetValues(ch As Range) As Object
    Dim dict As Object, rng As Range, c As Range, v
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each c In ch.Parent.Range(ch, ch.Parent.Cells(Rows.count, ch.Column).End(xlUp)).Cells
        v = Trim(c.Value)
        If Len(v) > 0 And Not dict.exists(v) Then
            dict.Add c.Address, v
        End If
    Next c
    Set GetValues = dict
End Function

'(9)
'find a header on a row: returns Nothing if not found
Function HeaderCell(rng As Range, sHeader As String) As Range
    Dim rv As Range, c As Range
    For Each c In rng.Parent.Range(rng, rng.Parent.Cells(rng.Row, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft)).Cells
        If Trim(c.Value) = sHeader Then
            Set rv = c
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c
    Set HeaderCell = rv
End Function

'(10)
Function GetLastRowInColumn(theWorksheet As Worksheet, col As String)
    With theWorksheet
        GetLastRowInColumn = .Range(col & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function

'(11)
Function GetLastRowInSheet(theWorksheet As Worksheet)
Dim ret
    With theWorksheet
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            ret = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            ret = 1
        End If
    End With
    GetLastRowInSheet = ret
End Function
```

**FULL MACRO:**

```
    Option Explicit

Sub LoopThroughDirectory()

    Const ROW_HEADER As Long = 10

    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim StartSht As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Integer, erow As Integer
    Dim Height As Integer
    Dim RowLast As Long
    Dim f As String
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim hc As Range, hc1 As Range, hc2 As Range, hc3 As Range, d As Range

    Set StartSht = Workbooks("masterfile.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")

    'turn screen updating off - makes program faster
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'location of the folder in which the desired TDS files are
    MyFolder = "C:\Users\trembos\Documents\TDS\progress\"

    'find the headers on the sheet
    Set hc1 = HeaderCell(StartSht.Range("B1"), "HOLDER")
    Set hc2 = HeaderCell(StartSht.Range("C1"), "CUTTING TOOL")

    'create an instance of the FileSystemObject
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'get the folder object
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(MyFolder)
    i = 2


    'loop through directory file and print names
'(1)
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If LCase(Right(objFile.Name, 3)) = "xls" Or LCase(Left(Right(objFile.Name, 4), 3)) = "xls" Then
'(2)

            'Open folder and file name, do not update links
            Set WB = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=MyFolder & objFile.Name, UpdateLinks:=0)
            Set ws = WB.ActiveSheet
'(3)
                'find CUTTING TOOL on the source sheet
                Set hc = HeaderCell(ws.Cells(ROW_HEADER, 1), "CUTTING TOOL")
                If Not hc Is Nothing Then

                    Set dict = GetValues(hc.Offset(1, 0))
                    If dict.count > 0 Then
                        Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                        'add the values to the masterfile, column 3
                        d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
                    End If
                Else
                    'header not found on source worksheet
                End If
'(4)
                'find HOLDER on the source sheet
                Set hc3 = HeaderCell(ws.Cells(ROW_HEADER, 1), "HOLDER")
                If Not hc3 Is Nothing Then

                    Set dict = GetValues(hc3.Offset(1, 0))
                    If dict.count > 0 Then
                        Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc1.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                        'add the values to the master list, column 2
                        d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
                    End If
                Else
                    'header not found on source worksheet
                End If
'(5)
            With WB
               'print TDS information
                For Each ws In .Worksheets
                        'print the file name to Column 1
                        StartSht.Cells(i, 1) = objFile.Name
                        'print TDS name from J1 cell to Column 4
                        With ws
                            .Range("J1").Copy StartSht.Cells(i, 4)
                        End With
                        i = GetLastRowInSheet(StartSht) + 1
                'move to next file
                Next ws
'(6)
                'close, do not save any changes to the opened files
                .Close SaveChanges:=False
            End With
        End If
    'move to next file
    Next objFile
    'turn screen updating back on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
'(7)
End Sub

'(8)
'get all unique column values starting at cell c
Function GetValues(ch As Range) As Object
    Dim dict As Object, rng As Range, c As Range, v
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each c In ch.Parent.Range(ch, ch.Parent.Cells(Rows.count, ch.Column).End(xlUp)).Cells
        v = Trim(c.Value)
        If Len(v) > 0 And Not dict.exists(v) Then
            dict.Add c.Address, v
        End If
    Next c
    Set GetValues = dict
End Function

'(9)
'find a header on a row: returns Nothing if not found
Function HeaderCell(rng As Range, sHeader As String) As Range
    Dim rv As Range, c As Range
    For Each c In rng.Parent.Range(rng, rng.Parent.Cells(rng.Row, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft)).Cells
        If Trim(c.Value) = sHeader Then
            Set rv = c
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c
    Set HeaderCell = rv
End Function

'(10)
Function GetLastRowInColumn(theWorksheet As Worksheet, col As String)
    With theWorksheet
        GetLastRowInColumn = .Range(col & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function

'(11)
Function GetLastRowInSheet(theWorksheet As Worksheet)
Dim ret
    With theWorksheet
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            ret = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            ret = 1
        End If
    End With
    GetLastRowInSheet = ret
End Function
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that the headercell function returns an appropriate result?

Comment: Yes, when running the full Macro, the headercell function works properly. Everything in the full Macro is working and outputs exactly what I am looking for. I am trying to alter the full macro to work with my textbox and search button for one single file _(since in the full macro, it is set open to open multiples files in one folder)_ @Raystafarian

Comment: Sorry, but it's really hard to perform the remote troubleshooting of this gigantic code base without any sample data available. Please debug your own app as much as possible, then narrow down your question and post the updated/edited version. Best regards,

Comment: Feel free to ask any questions you need to clarify. It's not really possible for me to ask a question without providing all of the code. As I said in the main question, my current problem is on the line that says `StartSht.Cells(i, 1) = objFile.Name` . I was hoping since I keep getting the same error that there would be some small fix needed that I'm not noticing. Both sets of code are almost identical, just with opening the file taken out of the smaller macro. Any ideas? @AlexBell

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your altered macro. You commented off the line (see section '(3)):

```
'Set WB = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=MyFolder & objFile.Name, UpdateLinks:=0)
```

while still using this variable `WB` later in the code (see section '(5))

```
With WB
```

That's why you got that 'object var is not set' error message. You have to fix this part. Hope this may help.

Comment: Yes, that is definitely a problem. The issue is I do not know how to go about correcting it since, in the altered macro, I do not need to open a folder. When I try to keep that Set WB line in, I get back the same object not defined error. Any ideas of what I could replace this with?

Comment: The answer was already given to you. Please check it accepted and should you have more questions, please post them separately. Best regards,

Comment: I have posted a separate question already. Thank you for trying to help but this did not answer my question